# Is it OK to mention Glassdoor to a recruiter?

Tags: recruitment, employer, review

I get these job offers from time to time and sometimes I ask for the name of the company. Some recruiters are more willing than others to reveal the companies name. As an excuse, I say that I need to check them out on the Glassdoor's site. Or if I don't like the company after letting me know the name I say:

> I checked their Glassdoor reviews and I've decided to pass the
>   opportunity at this time.

My question is do the recruiters or employers realize how much of an influence the Glassdoor site has on their success in hiring? Do recruiter try to "hide" Glassdoor's exposure if the company has a bad review? I know they can't prevent me from using this site but can mentioning this site raise certain flags? Let's say a recruiter can tell a company they have bad reviews and it's going to be more difficult to find people for them.  Or the site doesn't really matter and there is always enough demand in spite of the bad reviews?

Comment: Glassdoor is not everything. Better to touch with any experienced employee to know real things about company.  But still you can ask to recruiter about reviews so they can at least get aware about reviews about their company.

Comment: @HelpingHands Asking an employee who I never met is little weird.

Comment: @Grasper That's the point of the interview process. The company is not just interviewing you, but you are also interviewing them. The people who write reviews are the people who tend to have the strongest feelings (and I believe tend to be strong negative feelings). You should make decisions on your own and not what other people have to say - you don't know what may have driven them to write their review and how honest it is.

Comment: @Grasper - I agree but try to find reference in friends if anyone worked or working for same company. Just to decide everything based on glassdoor seems bit risky :) You might lose good opportunity. On glassdoor everyone write their experience with X company. Some have bad and some have good.

Comment: "As an excuse, I say that I need to check them out on the Glassdoor's site." Do you really need an excuse? I don't. I just tell 3rd party recruiters that I do not work with 3rd party recruiters that don't have exclusivity with a particular employer. In my profession of software developer, 3rd party recruiters without exclusivity never have access to job postings that I do not have access to (within at least 24 hours to 72 hours). My potential employers all use at least one of the following: Angel's list, StackOverflow, craigslist, dice, indeed, or monster. I don't need to go thru a 3rd party.

Comment: A renowned webshop in my country had outstanding reviews on Glassdoor, but when I went there for an interview I hated the culture. Opposite thing for the company I now work for: negative reports in the media, bad reviews on Glassdoor, but I love the job and company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People have their own ways of checking out whether a company is the right for for them or not. Glassdoor is one of many different ways to check this. Some people might check Google Reviews (although more unlikely) or go on LinkedIn and see what people have to say about them on there. ***It's up to you to do your research and decide***.

> do the recruiters or employers realize how much of an influence the
>   Glassdoor site has on their success in hiring?

Some might, some won't. I'd be confident in saying that quite a lot of people have no idea this site exists at all. I didn't until a couple of months ago, but that's just me.

> Do recruiter try to "hide" Glassdoor's exposure if the company has a
>   bad review?

There is a chance that some companies might, but there's really no way to know unless there is a couple of positive reviews sprinkled into a sea of negative reviews. Even if they do, so what? They're just '*firefighting*'. I'm not saying I agree with that, but they might be.

> I know they can't prevent me from using this site but can mentioning
>   this site raise certain flags?

Yes, maybe. I mean on one hand you're doing your research which is good. If you find something negative about the company then that might be a bit awkward, but if you find out a company has a terrible rating for legitimate reason, *do you really want to pursue it further*, ***really***?

> Let's say a recruiter can tell a company they have bad reviews and
>   it's going to be more difficult to find people for them. Or the site
>   doesn't really matter and there is always enough demand in spite of
>   the bad reviews?

Again, it's subjective. It depends on the reviews they're getting. Some companies will care and not like having negative reviews about them. Others might not care and simply see it as an opportunity to change and do something different. ***It depends on the company and what you as a potential candidate wants to do about it.***

Answer (score 2):

Every company (at least the good ones) should expect you to research them when applying for a job. It shows interest and an ability to make an informed decision. Their goal is to find qualified candidates, but they need to hire those that are going to be productive and stay. Fooling people into taking a job is a foolish and short-term solution that leads to lack of productivity (They're lucky if people just do enough.) and increased turn-over.

Glassdoor is just one way to go about your search. I wouldn't mention it by name because everyone just thinks "salary" or negative comments when they hear it.

If you want to build a relationship with a recruiter and they tell you they have a job, but can't give you the name until you get past their initial interview, that's for you to decide if it is worth it. My experience is once you work with these people, they'll give you the name if they think you are qualified and interested. Delaying this process gives you reason to delay your decision since you didn't even know the name of the company to do any research.

People see information as power and tend to hold onto it tightly.